# Dynamic Class Initiation AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

I´m trying to initialize a class, based on a concatenation of a string and a number.
All my classes are public.

This is my code:

```
public function setCurrentPath(pathNumber:String)
    {
        var pth_class:Class = getDefinitionByName('Pth'+pathNumber) as Class;
        var pth:MovieClip = new pth_class();
        addChild(pth)
        pth.getXY();


    }
```

So I´m getting Error #1065.

Any help?

Yes I have up on my class file import flash.utils.*

Comment: I think I get the error at 'var pth_class:Class = getDefinitionByName('Pth'+pathNumber) as Class;' Yes to all questions

Comment: if I trace("Pth"+pathNumber) I get 'Pth1' it´s a string not a class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your pth_class variable null?

If so, there are a couple of reasons this might be the case:

1) You haven't input the correct fully qualified class name of your class.  E.g com.myClasses.Pth1

or

2)

If you're instanciating classes dynamically like this and there is no other "regular" reference to the class (such as blah = new Pth1()) then the "Pth1" class won't be included in the compilation process.

To get around this I think you can supply arguments to the compiler to force it to compile those classes OR you can manually include references to them in your existing code:

```
p1:Pth1;
p2:Pth2;
```

Comment: if I use trace(getDefinitionByName("Pth1")) I get "Pth1" Class.
if I use trace(getDefinitionByName("Pth"+pathNumber)) I get the error.
I´m passing the string '1' to pathNumber.

Comment: I got it the argument must be a number not a string. So I was passing '1' for pathNumber (a string), so I converted to number and it works :).

Comment: "Pth"+pathNumber should be the same whether pathNumber is "1" (String) or 1 (int).